# How to use as_json in a controller to return a model's method display_name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

In my user model, I have a method display_name to output the user's full name.

```
user.rb (id, first_name, last_name, email, ...)
  def display_name
    [first_name, last_name].compact.join(' ')
  end
```

I'm trying to get my controller to return display_name like so:

```
  def show
    json_response({
      user: user.as_json(only: [:id, :display_name, :email])
    })
  end
```

Problem is, the controller is only sending id and email, not display_name.. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json):

> To include the result of some method calls on the model use :methods:

```
user.as_json(methods: :permalink)
# => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
#      "created_at" => "2006/08/01", "awesome" => true,
#      "permalink" => "1-konata-izumi" }
```

Also:

> The option include_root_in_json controls the top-level behavior of as_json. If true, as_json will emit a single root node named after the object’s type. The default value for include_root_in_json option is false.

```
user = User.find(1)
user.as_json
# => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
#     "created_at" => "2006/08/01", "awesome" => true}

ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true

user.as_json
# => { "user" => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
#                  "created_at" => "2006/08/01", "awesome" => true } }
```

> This behavior can also be achieved by setting the :root option to true as in:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.as_json(root: true)
# => { "user" => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
#                  "created_at" => "2006/08/01", "awesome" => true } }
```

So, probably something along the lines of:

```
user.as_json(only: [:id, :email], methods: :display_name, root: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
user.as_json(only: [:id, :email], methods: [:display_name])
```

or

```
user.as_json(only: [:id, :email]).merge({'display_name': user.display_name})
```

Or have a serializer